# Is it possible to mix pydantic BaseModels and Starlette Request?

Tags: python, fastapi, rate-limiting

#### Goal

My goal is to build a simple api to crack password hashes using fastapi and John the ripper.
For now, my api takes only one Post request with the hash to be cracked and some optional information on the original password (minimal length, maximal length etc). Ultimately, it will send this hash to a backend cluster running a containerized John the Ripper to crack the hash.
To encompass all the information that I wanted to be present in the Post request, I created a BaseModel subclass with the information that I needed (see code below).

#### Where am at

I want to implement rate limiting so that only a certain number of calls is allowed per ip address and per minute or hour. After some research, I decided to use the solution provided by slowapi as follow :

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded
from starlette.requests import Request


class HashType(str, Enum):
    md5 = "md5"
    sha1 = "sha1"

class HashRequest(BaseModel, Request):
    hash: str
    type: Optional[HashType] = None
    min_length: Optional[int] = None
    max_length: Optional[int] = None
    special_chars: Optional[bool] = None

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address)
app = FastAPI()
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)


@app.post("/")
@limiter.limit("10/minute")
@limiter.limit("100/hour")
async def send_hash(request: HashRequest):
    ## TODO: communicate with backend
    return {"message":"request recieved", "hash":request.hash}
```

slowapi requires the request argument to be explicitly passed to my endpoint and it to be of the type Request of starlette.requests. My solution was to use multiple inheritance, making HashRequest inherit from BaseModel and Request.

When I try to send a Post request to the api I have the error: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'hash'.

Command to send the request:

```
curl -X 'POST'   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'   -H 'accept: application/json'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{
    "hash":"foo"
}'
```

Comment: The regular way to do this would be to have `async def send_hash(hash: HashToCrack, request: Request):` where `HashToCrack` is the model you've defined, with just `BaseModel` as the parent class. Doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.starlette.io/requests/) you can see what there is in your request object Body

There are a few different interfaces for returning the body of the request:

The request body as bytes: `await request.body()`

The request body, parsed as form data or multipart: `await request.form()`

The request body, parsed as JSON: `await request.json()`

You can also access the request body as a stream, using the async for syntax:

in your case you should use:

```py
my_hash = request.json['hash']
```

if you want to use a pydantic model:

```py
class HashRequest(BaseModel):
    hash: str
    type: Optional[HashType] = None
    min_length: Optional[int] = None
    max_length: Optional[int] = None
    special_chars: Optional[bool] = None
```

```py
@app.get("/")
@limiter.limit("10/minute")
@limiter.limit("100/hour")
def get_role(hash_obj: HashRequest):
    ## TODO: communicate with backend
    return {"message": "request recieved", "hash": hash_obj.hash}
```